# How to access config from local.php

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am moving my old password encrypt class from ZF1 to ZF2.  In my original code I used the zend registry to store the encryption salt value pulled from the application.ini file.  In ZF2 the logical place for this setting to go would be the local.php file in config/autoload folder.

**My question is** how do I access the salt setting specified in the **`local.php`** file?

I have tried

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
```

but all this does is produce the error

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object
in C:\Users\Garry Childs\Documents\My Webs\freedomw\vendor\freedom\Zend\Filter\EncryptPassword.php on line 59
```

I have also tried to add the following function to my **`module.php`** file

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```

and used

```
$this->getConfig();
```

to no avail.

Please can someone point me in the right direction, many thanks.

Comment: Where are you trying to access it from? In your first example you aren't actually getting an ServiceLocator instance.

Answer (score 0):

would say that you have to make a factory for your password encrypt class and get the salt from `ServiceLocator` in the factory and inject the salt from the config into your class (either in constructor or by using some setter).

So something like this:

In your `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\Filter\EncryptPassword' => 'My\Filter\EncryptPasswordFactory',
    )
)
```

And then in your `My\Filter\EncryptPasswordFactory.php`:

```
<?php
namespace My\Filter;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class EncryptPasswordFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return EncryptPasswordService
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        $salt = ...get salt from config...
        $encryptPasswordService = new EncryptPasswordService($salt);
        return $encryptPasswordService;
```

*...or make a setSalt method or whatever you think is nicest...*

```
    }
}
```

Your `My\Filter\EncryptPasswordService.php`:

```
<?php
namespace My\Filter;

class EncryptPasswordSevice
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return EncryptPasswordService
     */
    public function __construct($salt)
    {
        use your $salt
    }
}
```

Now you can get your `My\Filter\EncryptPassword` anywhere where you have access to a serviceManager instance (or serviceLocator instance) like this:

```
$encryptPasswordService = $serviceManager->get('My\Filter\EncryptPassword');
```